# Run Minikube within Docker-Container

Tags: docker, minikube

I try to run minikube inside a docker container for test an development purposes.

For this I have installed docker in an container inherited from ubuntu:latest.

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y ca-certificates curl gnupg supervisor
RUN mkdir -p /var/log/supervisor
RUN install -m 0755 -d /etc/apt/keyrings

RUN curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | gpg --dearmor -o /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg

RUN chmod a+r /etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg
RUN echo \
    "deb [arch="$(dpkg --print-architecture)" signed-by=/etc/apt/keyrings/docker.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu \
    "$(. /etc/os-release && echo "$VERSION_CODENAME")" stable" | \
    tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
RUN curl -Lo minikube https://storage.googleapis.com/minikube/releases/latest/minikube-linux-amd64 \
    && chmod +x minikube
RUN cp minikube /usr/local/bin && rm minikube  

RUN curl -LO "https://dl.k8s.io/release/$(curl -L -s https://dl.k8s.io/release/stable.txt)/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl"
RUN install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl
RUN chmod +x kubectl
```

**Commands to build and run:**

```
docker build -f Dockerfile.ubuntu -t dindubuntu .
docker run --privileged --name dub -itd dindubuntu
```

If the container has started then I started dockerd and `docker run hello-world` correctly executed. After that I start `minikube start --force`

```
* minikube v1.30.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 (docker/amd64)
! minikube skips various validations when --force is supplied; this may lead to unexpected behavior

! Exiting due to GUEST_DRIVER_MISMATCH: The existing "minikube" cluster was created using the "docker" driver, which is incompatible with requested "none" driver.
* Suggestion: Delete the existing 'minikube' cluster using: 'minikube delete', or start the existing 'minikube' cluster using: 'minikube start --driver=docker'

root@57536424e474:/# minikube delete
* Deleting "minikube" in docker ...
* Removing /root/.minikube/machines/minikube ...
* Removed all traces of the "minikube" cluster.
root@57536424e474:/# minikube start                        
* minikube v1.30.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 (docker/amd64)
* Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: none, ssh
* The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges. If you wish to continue as root, use --force.
* If you are running minikube within a VM, consider using --driver=none:
*   https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/

X Exiting due to DRV_AS_ROOT: The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges.

root@57536424e474:/# minikube start --force
* minikube v1.30.1 on Ubuntu 22.04 (docker/amd64)
! minikube skips various validations when --force is supplied; this may lead to unexpected behavior
* Automatically selected the docker driver. Other choices: none, ssh
* The "docker" driver should not be used with root privileges. If you wish to continue as root, use --force.
* If you are running minikube within a VM, consider using --driver=none:
*   https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/reference/drivers/none/
! docker is currently using the vfs storage driver, consider switching to overlay2 for better performance
* Using Docker driver with root privileges
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Pulling base image ...
* Creating docker container (CPUs=2, Memory=7900MB) ...
! StartHost failed, but will try again: creating host: create: creating: setting up container node: preparing volume for minikube container: docker run --rm --name minikube-preload-sidecar --label created_by.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=true --label name.minikube.sigs.k8s.io=minikube --entrypoint /usr/bin/test -v minikube:/var gcr.io/k8s-minikube/kicbase:v0.0.39@sha256:bf2d9f1e9d837d8deea073611d2605405b6be904647d97ebd9b12045ddfe1106 -d /var/lib: exit status 127
stdout:

stderr:
docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: unable to apply cgroup configuration: failed to write 2814: write /sys/fs/cgroup/docker/dce8e8b2de225d576fdfb75a8aabb453fbe5e8890f284ea008c7701694979915/cgroup.procs: no such file or directory: unknown.
```

How get I running a minikube cluster inside a docker container? Or is that generally not possible?

*A docker related question of mine was closed by stackoverflow but its code available so it should be correct.*

Answer (score 0):

Just run Minikube.  Explicitly specify the [Docker driver](https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/docker/) if you need to.

```bash
minikube set driver docker
minikube start
kubectl get namespace
```

With the Docker driver, the entire Kubernetes "cluster" is in a single container.  It seems like what your Dockerfile is trying to set up is a complete Kubernetes environment encapsulated inside a single container, and `minikube start --driver=docker` already does that on its own.

There's not really any value to putting the `minikube` CLI tool in a container, and trying to hide that inside a Docker-in-Docker environment only adds extra complexity.  Consider that locally you're going to need tools like `kubectl` to interact with the cluster, and those will need a network path to reach it.  You mostly can't avoid needing `kubectl` on the host, and reaching from there to a container inside a DinD environment requires publishing a port out of the DinD container itself.  That's more complexity than you really need.

The other thing to consider here is that `minikube` itself is not a long-running tool.  It creates a container or VM and does some bootstrapping tasks, but `minikube` itself doesn't stay running beyond that.  It makes a little less sense to try to package a tool like this inside a container.

Comment: (Also consider [kind](https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/) as another official tool that creates a Kubernetes cluster in containers; a little more oriented towards simulated multi-node setups, and without a VM-based mode.  But again, directly run it on the host and let it create containers.)

Comment: The problem is, that my entire infrastructure (VS Code, Gitlab, Jenkins, ...) is running within docker containers. I don't have access to the underlying system to install additional applications. The only what I can make is to start docker container. Maybe I don't need minikube, maybe it is possible to run kubernetes directly within the container.